# extract the keyword from the log file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, sh

I need to filter the keyword based on my grep command. The below is my log file.

```
2018-03-20T15:07:33,432 INFO  [26b604b7-43cf-4bdc-9ffb-6bae323f8fc5 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-55([])]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:compile(429)) - Compiling command(queryId=hive_20180320150733_cb6c088a-2b53-4826-891a-2dd905b16cef): SELECT * FROM table limit 5
```

I need to extract the particular query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table limit 5
```

I tried like this

```
grep -oE 'SELECT * FROM [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*' hive-server2.log
```

tried with awk also

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "" }
 /Executing command\(queryId/{ sub(/.*queryId=[^[:space:]]+: /,""); q=$0 }
 /s3:\/\//{ print "," q }' OFS=',' hive-server2.log
```

Nothing works for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sed**

change the all string previous to SELECT (including SELECT) with the string "SELECT"

```
  sed -n 's/.*SELECT/SELECT/p'  file
```

**grep**

you can run this(display regexp found):

```
 grep -oE 'SELECT .*' file
```

Comment: The above query also fetches all the logs. I need only this "SELECT * FROM table limit 5". any help would be appraciated

Comment: Great its working, But another doubt. how to change the query to support both the case like upper or lower cases.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, if you want the grep to cover also  `"select * from table limit"` (lower case) ,so you can add the `-i` flag to the grep. `grep -oEi 'SELECT .*' file`

Answer (score 2):

If your actual Input_file is same as shown sample then following may help you.

```
awk '{sub(/.*SELECT/,"SELECT")} 1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
awk 'match($0,/SELECT.*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);}'  Input_file
```

Comment: The above queries fetches all the matches with the logs. I need like only the query ex:"SELECT * FROM table limit 5"

Comment: @TejuPriya, 2nd solution will match only `select` one. you could remove `1` from it and it will only print the Select things in it.

Comment: @TejuPriya, removed `1` now, please check once and let me know if it is helping you?